# ASP.NET Routing: Return specific formats depending on extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to create a MVC 4 application, and I'm kinda new to this.
How can I map a route to a specific file extension?

I want to do something like this:

```
Controller/Action/ (maybe an ID)
```

This should return a MVC View, for the user to see in their browser.

In another scenario:

```
Controller/Action/ (Maybe an ID) .json
```

or:

```
Controller/Action/ (Maybe an ID) .xml
```

This should return the same object, but in JSON or XML, for webservices to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much mapping to an extension - MVC 4 URLs don't need to correspond directly to files. Instead, you register routes, which correspond to controller actions. So for this, you could have the following routes:

- `/something/page/{ID}` which links to `SomeController.ShowPage(int ID)` which returns a `ViewResult`
- `/something/page/{ID}/xml` which links to `SomeController.PageAsXML(int ID)` which returns an `XDocument`
- `/something/page/{ID}/json which links to`SomeController.PageAsJSON(int ID)`which returns a`JsonResult`

These routes are registered by a method called in the Application_Start() code when your server starts up. A simple route registration for the XML page example would look something like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
        "PageView_XML",
        "{controller}/page/{id}/xml",
        new { id = "" }  
        );
    }
}
```

Here, the route is called `"PageView_XML"` to fit in with a hypothetical naming scheme in which there is also a `"PageView"` and a `"PageView_JSON"`. Names must be unique.
Any URL matching the pattern `{controller}/page/{id}/xml` will use this route, where anything written like `{this}` is a parameter that will be matched to any string in the right place. You'll notice that `{id}` is given a default value of `""` (an empty string), which is probably not very useful; you can pick something that your controller method will recognise and use to show a suitable error page instead.

You can mix `{param}` tags and text, so `{controller}/page/{id}-xml` or even `{controller}/page/{id}_{format}` will work. I'm not so sure about `{controller}/page/{id}.xml` or `{controller}/page/{id}.{format}` because it might handle `.` differently.

Take a look at [the MSDN info on routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), particularly [this bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#adding_routes_to_an_mvc_application) for a little more detail on adding routes. [O'Reilly](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449320317/ch_Routing.html) also has some handy info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension method called AddUrlPathExtensionMapping on the Json and Xml Mediatypeformatters of MVC4 Web API to enable you to request data in those particular formats.